# why this error appears when i build new job in hudson CI tool and the job failed?

Tags: java, continuous-integration, hudson, oracle-adf

```
[ViewController] $ cmd.exe /C '"ant.bat -file build.xml deploy && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'
'ant.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several choices.

1. Specify path to the folder with ant. (use command cd, you should be in folder with ant)
2. Set the environment variables for ant
3. Try this: C:\path_to_ant\ant.bat -file build.xml deploy && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%